# How to use java.math.BigInteger in jjs / Nashorn?

Tags: javascript, java, biginteger, fibonacci, nashorn

I would like to use java.math.BigInteger in a nashorn / jss JavaScript.

By way of example, let's say I want to calculate Fibonacci sequence numbers. Numbers will need to remain exact, even if they become very large.

Working Java code looks like this:

```
public static BigInteger fibonacci(int n) {
  BigInteger prev = new BigInteger("0");
  if (n == 0) return prev;

  BigInteger next = new BigInteger("1");
  if (n == 1) return next;

  BigInteger fib = null;
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    fib = prev.add(next);
    prev = next;
    next = fib;
  }
  return fib;
}
```

We can test with:

- n=77:  5527939700884757
- n=78:  8944394323791464
- n=79: 14472334024676221

So far so good.

Equivalent JavaScript code below:

```
function fibonacci(n) {
  var BigInteger = Java.type("java.math.BigInteger");
  prev = new BigInteger("0");
  if (n == 0) return prev;

  next = new BigInteger("1");
  if (n == 1) return next;

  var i, fib = null;
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    fib = prev.add(next);
    prev = next;
    next = fib;
  }
  return fib;
}
```

Now we get:

- n=77:  5527939700884757
- n=78:  8944394323791464
- n=79: 14472334024676220

Note that the value for 79 is one off - it's wrong.

I suspect the problem is that somewhere, the BigNumber values are re-interpreted as plain JavaScript Numbers. (by "somewhere" I suspect this already happens as the supposedly BigInteger is passed to the .add method)

For example, if I you do:

```
var BigInteger = Java.type("java.math.BigInteger");
print(new BigInteger("14472334024676221"));
```

The output is `14472334024676220`, not `14472334024676221`.
This happens even if I explicitly call `.toString()` on the BigInteger object.

How do I get past this?

UPDATE: @Dici asked if I looked for a threshold. I did - I found:

```
var str, BigInteger = Java.type("java.math.BigInteger");
str = "9999999999999998";
print(str + ": " + new BigInteger(str));
str = "9999999999999999";
print(str + ": " + new BigInteger(str));
```

will output:

- 9999999999999998: 9999999999999998
- 9999999999999999: 10000000000000000

I'm not sure it it's a matter of "treshold", or of some particular numbers having inaccuracies though.

UPDATE 2:

This is now reported as a bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146264
Bug report was done by a Oracle JDK/Nashorn developer so I guess it's the real thing. Keeping my fingers crossed.

Comment: Did you try looking for a threshold for this bug (under the threshold, works fine, above it, bug) ?

Comment: `I'm not sure it it's a matter of "treshold", or of some particular numbers having inaccuracies though` well if the next number has the same problem, and the next one, and the next one etc it's a threshold, otherwise it's something else.

Comment: @Dici. Ok. But any idea on how to overcome this?

Comment: Nope, I was just trying to understand the nature of the problem

Comment: @Dici my guess is that BigInteger (and BigDecimal) are made to look like javascript Number, and that the evaluation happens "too soon" if you catch my drift. If you take the update code, and append toString() to the BigInteger instances, then the output is still the same. That is IMO impossible if the toString() would be applied to the actual java object. So I suspect the bigInteger is first converted to JavaScript Number, loses precision, and then toString() is called on that JavaScript Number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is an issue. A bug has been filed -> https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8146264

JSType and few other places have "instanceof Number" check -- not sure if fixing JSType.toStringImpl alone will do. In any case, I've a workaround - not very pretty one - but a workaround nevertheless. You can call java.lang.Object.toString method on those objects thereby avoiding Nashorn's JSType string conversion code.

```
function fibonacci(n) {
  var BigInteger = Java.type("java.math.BigInteger");
  prev = new BigInteger("0");
  if (n == 0) return prev;

  next = new BigInteger("1");
  if (n == 1) return next;

  var i, fib = null;
  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    fib = prev.add(next);
    prev = next;
    next = fib;
  }
  return fib;
}

function javaToString(obj) {
    var javaToStringMethod = (new java.lang.Object()).toString;
    var call = Function.prototype.call;
    return call.call(javaToStringMethod, obj);
}

print(javaToString(fibonacci(77)))
print(javaToString(fibonacci(78)))
print(javaToString(fibonacci(79)))

var str, BigInteger = Java.type("java.math.BigInteger");
str = "9999999999999998";
print(str + ": " + javaToString(new BigInteger(str)));
str = "9999999999999999";
print(str + ": " + javaToString(new BigInteger(str)));
```

Comment: Marvelous! I realize it's ugly but that's ok - workarounds usually are and having some working solution is way better than having nothing at all. However if it is decided that Nashorn won't change it's behavior in treating the big numbers, then this workwound will need to be documented prominently here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/nashorn/api.html#sthref22

Comment: Actually, a more straight forward implementation of javaToString function can use java.util.Objects.toString method.

Answer (score 2):

I took your example:

```
var BigInteger = Java.type("java.math.BigInteger");
print(new BigInteger("14472334024676221"));
```

Started the program in debug mode and noticed that `toString` method of `BigInteger` was not used. So I created a simple class:

```
public class ToString {
    private final BigInteger x;

    public ToString(BigInteger x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return x.toString();
    }
}
```

And used it in order to output the `BigInteger`, and it worked:

```
ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine jsEngine = scriptEngineManager.getEngineFactories().get(0).getScriptEngine();
String script = "var BigInteger = Java.type(\"java.math.BigInteger\");\n" +
        "var ToString = Java.type(\"com.stackoverflow.inner.ToString\");\n" +
        "var ts = new ToString(new BigInteger(\"14472334024676221\"));\n" +
        "print(ts);";
jsEngine.eval(script); // prints 14472334024676221
```

Then I suspected that Nashorn used some intermediate conversion before converting `BigInteger` to `String` so I created a breakpoint at `BigInteger.doubleValue()` and it triggered when bare `BigInteger` was printed. Here is the problematic stack trace to let you understand Nashorn's logic:

```
  at java.math.BigInteger.doubleValue(BigInteger.java:3888)
  at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.JSType.toStringImpl(JSType.java:976)
  at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.JSType.toString(JSType.java:327)
  at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.JSType.toCharSequence(JSType.java:341)
  at jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.NativeString.constructor(NativeString.java:1140)
```

And the problematic Nashorn's code `JSType.toStringImpl`:

```
if (obj instanceof Number) {
    return toString(((Number)obj).doubleValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Yeah I suspected too that at the javascript end, we're not actually talking to the Java BigInteger object, but rather to something that is already converted to JavaScript Number. What do you think? Is this is a bug? Might there be some, any, other way to still work with BigInteger without having to add Java classes ourselves?

Comment: @RolandBouman, all types inside Nashorn are automatically overwriten with `JSType`'s version of `toString`, so unfortunately I see no way of printing the value without external class, a call to `toString(radix)` is intercepted by `JSType` as well.

Comment: Thanks for your analysis. Damn, this is a real disappointment - that JSType.toStringImpl is evil. It has no business deciding on its own that the double value is good enough IMO. I forwarded the issue to the nashorn-dev mailing list. I hope they'll respond and fix it. https://www.mail-archive.com/nashorn-dev@openjdk.java.net/msg04893.html